# Classroom.Courses.Students.create returns error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm writing a script to enroll all my students (2,000) each one in his own classroom.
referring to the [Method page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create) I wrote a simple sentence like this:

```
Classroom.Courses.Students.create({
    "courseId": "9898688798",
    "profile": {
      "name": {
        "familyName": "Xxxxxx",
        "givenName": "Yyyy"
      },
      "emailAddress": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
  });
```

but I receive this error:
Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You linked to some web API documentation. Are you calling an API here? If so, please edit your post to show how this code is translated to a web request. If not, can you tell us what the context is? (A Google SDK?) In any case, please add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: Hi Noah, sorry I forgot the language TAG, the code I posted is a piece of a google script.

Comment: Please, please. It's very important for me to complete the script to enroll the students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

As the error you are getting says, this method requires two or three parameters, and you're only providing one.

#### Solution:

If you start typing the method you'll see a popup displaying the required parameters for this method:

- **resource**: referring to the [student resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students#Student), which is the [request body](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create#request-body) that has to be provided for the API method.
- **courseId**: the identifier of the course to create the student in, which is the [path parameter](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create#path-parameters) for the API method.
- **optionalArgs**: [OPTIONAL] referring to any additional parameters you'd want to add, like [enrollmentCode](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create#query-parameters).

Also, for the first parameter, `resource`, three of the four fields from the `student resource` are read-only, so you only have to provide the `userId`, which can be one of the following:

- the numeric identifier for the user
- the email address of the user
- the string literal **"me"**, indicating the requesting user

#### Code snippet:

So in your example, you could do this:

```
const resource = {
  "userId": "myemail@gmail.com"
}
const courseId = "9898688798";
Classroom.Courses.Students.create(resource, courseId);
```

Comment: Hi lamblichus, thanks for your answer. Actually I copied the request body from the "Try this API" page. I misunterdestood how to use that page: if the "profile" section is read-only why the page lets you fill that section?

Comment: One more question, the Classroom.Courses.Students.create method is intended to work only with user belonging to the admin domain? or is possible to use it to enroll students from out of the admin  domain?

Comment: @LUCADELLAGHEZZA `if the "profile" section is read-only why the page lets you fill that section?`: Probably they didn't take into account which fields are read-only when building this.

Comment: @LUCADELLAGHEZZA Yes, I think you have to be a domain admin. If you're a teacher, you have to use `invitations.create()` instead https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#enroll_or_remove_students

Comment: Actually I'm the domain admin and the owner of the classroom, but the classroom guides says "Domain administrators can directly add students within their domain...", so I understand that is not possible. However our students can freely sign into our classrooms using any email domain. That's fun.

Comment: @LUCADELLAGHEZZA `so I understand that is not possible` What do you mean? What is not possible?

Comment: Is not possible to create a student profile if the student's domain is out from admin's domain.

Comment: @LUCADELLAGHEZZA Sure it's not possible. Being a domain admin doesn't give access to accounts outside the domain. I didn't understand your were asking this before, sorry.